# Open winforms just one time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed program, I need a form, when users open the application first time, I want to show them a settings form just 1 time. And will never see that form at the begininig. Is that possible without any DB controls?

thank you

Comment: Sure, you don't have to save the info in a db. You have to save a setting *somewhere*... you can save it in the registry, or in a file in the application folder, or anywhere else you want to save it.

Comment: thanks @neminem, I mean not saving to anywhere. .net has like this option? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `settings`! You can read on how to set these up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Once you have defined a setting you can use them like this

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun)
{
    MessageBox.Show("first run!");
    Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: That's saving a boolean flag to the AppData folder. Of course, there is no way of doing that without some kind of data persistence to hold the "first run" status.